# Using JS to create elements with onClick attribute to make function calls when used in a React Component

Tags: reactjs

I am sending multiple results from a search query as 'item' to a function which generates  elements. However, the function turns the onClick attribute value I assign into a string, hence each onClick event will not be recognised as a function call in JSX

The function in question is within renderResults.js:

```
function searchItemRenderer (item) {
    /*The container for all elements that will be rendered at #results*/
    var html = [];

    /*1st element to be added*/
    html.push("<p class='images'>");

    /*Subsequent 'html' array elements to be added from 'item' to form <img/> elements with attributes*/                                    
    html.push("<img src="+item.thumbnailUrl+" id="+item.index+" onClick={this.logMessage}>");   

    return html.join("");
}

export default function showResults () {        
    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(searchItemRenderer())
}
```

renderResults.js is then imported into a .jsx file containing the target component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import {showResults} from "./renderResults.js";

class Results extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.logMessage = this.logMessage.bind(this);
    }
    logMessage(){
        console.log("Image clicked!");
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="results" onLoad={showResults}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Results;
```

I tried inserting {this.logMessage} as a Javascript variable as shown below but it did not render:

```
html.push("<img src="+item.thumbnailUrl+" id="+item.index+" onClick="+{this.logMessage}+">");
```

Is there some way to have {this.logMessage} rendered as a React onClick function call event by the JS function? Should this work, "Image clicked!" should log into the console each time an image rendered in the browser is clicked

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```
html.push(<p class='images'>);
```

You don't need to push html string, just push jsx and also you don't need `html.join("");`

just return `html`

don't forget to add corresponding closing tags. :)

Comment: Thanks @Sameer and sorry about the late reply, I was tied up for the last week. 

Ok, but this approach only works in JSX. JS does not allow me to add HTML elements to an array since it is not an expression.  But you did get me thinking: If I import the stuff in the 'item' parameter to my JSX, I can build each <img/> element from there.

Let's see how it goes

Comment: `<p></p>` is a jsx element for react and it could be pushed to an array, you don't need to quote it in single or double quotes.